# xCode 6.3.2 - arm64 Conversion

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, nullreferenceexception

What is quickest way to convert old iOS Application written in ObjC to arm64.

When I updated valid architectures to arm64, I get tones of errors, framework missing, clangs.

Do xCode 6.3.2 Provide any help in conversion?[image]

Comment: what errors you get ?

Comment: @NullData: There are many but mostly framework/reference/lib path missing errors, when I remove arm64 from valid architecture, all errors disappear.

Comment: build active architecture only  go to release set NO, debug Yes

Comment: already tried, does not work.